# Sitecore login redirects to website and not Launchpad

Tags: azure, paas, identity-server, login

We are using azure alias URL *"https://abc.com/sitecore/login"* to access our prod CM site *"https://abc-1001-cm.azurewebsites.net/sitecore/login"*.

- Earlier we had Sitecore 9.0.1 without identity server and redirection was working fine.
- After upgrading to Sitecore 9.3 the azure alias URL is redirecting to identity server URL which shows the Sitecore login screen.
- Post login, it is redirecting to Sitecore website *"https://abc-1001-cm.azurewebsites.net/"* instead of Sitecore launch pad.

This issue happens intermittently even while using the CM app service URL to login Sitecore(*"https://abc-1001-cm.azurewebsites.net/sitecore/login"*)

**Basic information about application:**
Sitecore Version 9.3 (XP scaled) running on Azure PaaS with Application Gateway and CNAMES(alias URLs/DNS names) enabled.

Requesting a solution for the above issue.

Comment: Clear your cache and try again. It will work. If not once it shows site apple /Sitecore in url

Comment: Thanks for your response. This happens every time even after clearing cache. Wanted to know if there is any other solution to automatically route to launchpad than appending /sitecore at the end every time.

Comment: is this happening for every user or specific user?

Comment: This is happening for all users @MaheshRaghupathi